# How can design a config utility to work both statically and dynamically linked?

Tags: c++

I feel this issue may have a simple solution that's just not obvious to me - I have a config class that is used to store various configuration options loaded from an ini file, among other places. In my application, I have a library and client, and 2 configurations - build the library as a DLL and have the client link dynamically, or build them both together as a single binary.  So how can I have/use my config object in both the library and client?  If I include the config class definition in both, I assume it will give me link errors due to redefinitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I include the config class definition in both, I assume it will give me link errors due to redefinitions.

No, it won't. Windows DLLs do not respect the one definition rule. Basically, in Windows, ODR stops at the module boundary, i.e., ODR is respected *within* an executable and *within* a DLL, but not across them. Whether that's a good thing or not is not relevant, that's just how it is. So, you can include the definition of your config class in both the DLL and the executable. However, there will be two separate instances of the singleton (as I assume it is a singleton class, as config classes usually are), one in each module. In that sense, it won't be a true singleton, at least, not across the modules.

If you want a true singleton across the modules, you'll have to do a bit more work. You have two choices: master-slave or merging (or a "daisy chain").

The first option is to designate one module (e.g., the executable) as the module that instantiates (and keeps) the singleton object, and then you pass a pointer to that instance to all the "slave" modules which can then use it via a common interface (so both modules have the same *declaration* for the config class, but only one module creates it and passes it to the others). It would look something like this:

In the header file "config_class.h":

```
class ConfigClass {

  // a bunch of declarations...

  public:
    static ConfigClass& getInstance();  // the access-point for the singleton.
};

#ifdef MY_LIB_NOW_BUILDING_MASTER

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void setConfigClassInstance(ConfigClass* pobj);

#else

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void setConfigClassInstance(ConfigClass* pobj);

#endif
```

In the cpp file "config_class.cpp":

```
#include "config_class.h"

// a bunch of definitions for the config_class member functions.

#ifdef MY_LIB_NOW_BUILDING_MASTER

ConfigClass& ConfigClass::getInstance() {
  static ConfigClass instance( /*  */ );
  return instance;
};

#else

static ConfigClass* masterInstance;

void setConfigClassInstance(ConfigClass* pobj) {
  masterInstance = pobj;
};

ConfigClass& ConfigClass::getInstance() {
  return *masterInstance;
};

#endif
```

where, in the above example, you would call setConfigClassInstance from the master module (most likely the main executable) to set the config object for the DLLs, but make sure the DLLs don't require the config class during their static initialization (loading).

The second option is to either merge or daisy-chain your singletons. In this case, each module creates its own singleton instance, but then, using a similar scheme as above, they pass pointers to each other's instances, allowing them to be either merged into one instance (cross-linked), or you chain them together (e.g., like a circular linked-list or ring-list) and you dispatch the calls to the appropriate instance.

I think that for your application, the first option is probably the easiest.

N.B.: In non-Windows environments, the situation is entirely different, and none of the above applies.

Comment: the "If I include the config class definition in both, I assume it will give me link errors due to redefinitions." statement was for static linking (with the dll being built as a .lib), not dynamic; I believe with the solution you provided above, the same would still happen.  I am sure I can solve this with colorful use of preprocessor defines, but I was trying to avoid that particular method if possible.

Comment: @Rollie Ohh, so, if I get this right, lets say you have: main.cpp (app. code), lib.cpp (library code) and config.cpp (config class code). Which compile into main.o, lib.o and config.o. And then you build a version with "exe + dll" as "(main.o, config.o) + (lib.o, config.o)", and then you want to turn the dll into a static library, and naively try to link (main.o, config.o, lib.o, config.o) and get a ODR error. The solution is trivial, just don't link the config code more than once when building the static version. That's it.